# Stack Overflow search API for text in body

Tags: stackexchange-api

I am working on a project to identify certain text in the body of Stack Overflow questions. It works but for this one case it is not working. I am looking to see if through code I can find exposed access keys for AWS to understand the gravity of the situation. Here is the code:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
               'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
               'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
              }

url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&body=' + 'AKIAIHXBFL3ATI64QPAQ' + '&site=stackoverflow'

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
time.sleep(3)

if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    pagedata = gzip.decompress(response.read())
elif response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'deflate':
    pagedata = response.read()
elif response.info().get('Content-Encoding'):
    print('Encoding type unknown')
else:
    pagedata = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(pagedata, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

Here is the response from soup:

```
<html><body><p>{"items":[],"has_more":false,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":291}</p></body></html>
```

It returns and empty file. If I search for other text in the `body=**` parameter it does respond with a huge list of things. Am I doing something wrong or the API cannot do text search this specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like another API bug.

A workaround is to use the `q` parameter instead:
    [/2.2/search/advanced?q=AKIAIHXBFL3ATI64QPAQ&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=AKIAIHXBFL3ATI64QPAQ&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

This gives the same results as [this live site search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AKIAIHXBFL3ATI64QPAQ&mixed=0).  (Currently 2 questions)

---

Note that, irregardless, **this won't find *answers*** with the target text. The API is no good for that.

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) can find text in both questions and answers, but the results may be up to one week old.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried SEDE but it was very inefficient and kept timing out. Google big query has a public stackoverflow dataset which was pretty efficient but had data till March 2019 which is not bad. Thank you for the workaround. It definitely works for questions.